# MYSQL Error in creating Foreign Constain

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a database for my uni assignment but I'm having trouble with my foreign key constraint in line 47 of my code same as below;

```
CONSTRAINT Sessions_Screen_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (ScreenID) REFERENCES screen(ScreenID),
```

the error I'm receiving is

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

and I cant seem to get around it. if i remove the constraint though the script runs fine.

I've pasted the full script below:
Thankyou for your time

```
Drop Database IF EXISTS AE2_ISYS114;

CREATE Database AE2_ISYS114;

CREATE TABLE AE2_ISYS114.branch(
BranchID            char(2) NOT NULL,
BranchName          varchar(20),
BranchSuburb        varchar(15),
BranchPostCode      char(4),
PRIMARY KEY (BranchID)
);



CREATE TABLE AE2_ISYS114.movie(
MovieID                 char(2) NOT NULL,
MovieName               varchar(20),
MovieGenre              varchar(20),
MovieClassification     varchar(5),
PRIMARY KEY (MovieID)
);


CREATE TABLE AE2_ISYS114.screen(
ScreenID                char(2) NOT NULL,
BranchID                char(2),
ScreenCapacity          int(3),
PRIMARY KEY (BranchID,ScreenID),
CONSTRAINT Screen_Branch_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (BranchID) REFERENCES Branch(BranchID)
);


CREATE TABLE AE2_ISYS114.sessions(
SessionID               char(4) NOT NULL,
BranchID                char(2),
ScreenID                char(2),
MovieID                 char(2),
SessionDate             DATE,
SessionPrice            Decimal(4,2),
PRIMARY KEY (SessionID),
CONSTRAINT Sessions_Branch_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (BranchID) REFERENCES branch(BranchID),
CONSTRAINT Sessions_Screen_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (ScreenID) REFERENCES screen(ScreenID),
CONSTRAINT Sessions_Movie_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (MovieID) REFERENCES movie(MovieID)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL requires the referenced field (`screen.ScreenID`) to be indexed, and the referenced field should be the **leftmost** field in the index. As MySQL documentation on [using foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist.

`screen.ScreenID` field is part of the primary key of the `screen` table, however, it is **not** the leftmost field. You need to create a separate index on `screen.ScreenID` field to make the foreign key work.

Comment: OMG It took me 2 hours straight looking at the code just for you to point out that its the way I messed up in screen's Pkey thanks a lot

Comment: This happens to every developer, myself definitely included :)